Arch Linux Wayland RTX3070Ti нет изображения
Такой вопрос, у меня стоит arch linux на Asus Rox Strix (ноутбук).
В режимах встроенной графики и гибрида все работает.
А вот в режиме дискретной графики рабочий стол KDE Plasma запускается только под Х11. Под Wayland черный экран (не черный выключенный, а черный с подсветкой. иногда отображается мышь... и если двигать её она меняет свою иконку... как будто экран работает и рабочий стол работает, но изображения нету.
Пытался настраивать через ttl не получилось.
Почему то в режиме дискретной графики у меня отображается два дисплей порта
Unknown-1 и eDP-2
рабочий eDP-2, но все попытки переключится на него не дали успеха.
При отключении порта eDP-2 монитор полностью отключается.
У меня два окружения. х11 и Wayland.
Во всех режимах все работает отлично под любым окружением.
Но вот когда режим дискретной графики - вейленд...не работает...
Предоставлю любые данные о ПК. Что нужно ?

Была похожая проблема, попробуй более новый или более старый драйвер

@qwardo да, попробовал переустановить, не помогло.
Но... Я выполнил yay -Ss nvidia и получил список всех пакетов, где нашел такой:
nvidia-exec 0.2.9-1
Run programs in nvidia optimus setups with power management for Xorg and Wayland without log out
Установил, ну от части он помог. Если раньше в режиме дискретной графики изображения не было вообще, то теперь изображение есть, но порт Unknown-1 вместо eDP-2 и 60 фпс.
Конечно, это лучше чем было... Но буду искать еще варианты решения.
Не может такого быть, что бы решения не было. Я в линукс пока новичок всего 3-й день сижу на нем
